# how to add build rule in xcode 5.0.2

Tags: xcode, build-rules

I am trying to add j2objc build rule provided by google in my xcode project.  here is the link of procedure mentioned by google
'https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/wiki/XcodeBuildRule'
But I am unable to find any Add Build Rule option under Build Rule in my xcode.  'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AScreen_Shot_2014-06-03_at_4.43.02_PM.png'
 what is the alternative to add build rule in my project.  thanks in advance

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your project configuration? It should be there.

Answer (score 0):

If the add build rule button isn't visible, you can instead add a build rule via the menu bar. Select **Editor** > **Add Build Rule**.